# Can I get the kerning value of two characters using PIL?

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

Is it possible to get the kerning value of two characters in a font using  PIL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, PIL can only be used to render text, not get its metrics. You'll need to use either the appropriate Windows API functions, or the [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/) library (for which no stable Python bindings exist) in order to get kerning info.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't expose the metrics functions.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is, as Ignacio said, no.

That was the serious part of this answer. And now, for something completely different:

you can approximate *a* (not *the*, since you can't know by using PIL alone what is the design em size of the font) kerning value using something like:

```
import ImageFont
SAMPLE_SIZE= 128 # should provide sufficient resolution for kerning values

def get_a_kerning_value(font_descriptor, char1, char2):
    """See if there is some kerning value defined for a pair of characters
    Return the kerning value as an approximated percentage of the row height."""

    imagefont= ImageFont.truetype(font_descriptor, SAMPLE_SIZE)

    width1= imagefont.getsize(char1)[0]
    width2= imagefont.getsize(char2)[0]
    widths, height= imagefont.getsize(char1 + char2)

    return (widths - (width1 + width2))/float(height)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is kern-dump which will dump kern values for all glyph pairs in a font file:

https://github.com/adobe-type-tools/kern-dump